# UIImageJPEGRepresentation memory crash

Tags: ios

Im using a UIImageJPEGRepresentation to recreate the CoreData SQL data to imageData like this:

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(question.answer.image.image, 0.3);
```

It causes memory crashes on devices for users with more than 100 images for example. How can i fix this or make it much lighter?

Comment: You should share what the crash is, but `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, itself, is unlikely to be causing problems. (And reducing quality with 0.3 is rarely the right answer.) What's probably happening is that you're either holding on to too many of these in memory at one time or you have some strong reference cycle that's preventing them from getting released. Run your app through the Allocations tool in Instruments and see what the memory profile looks like. If the allocations graph is increasing, without ever falling back to some steady-state level, then you have some leak.

Comment: Please refer to WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) or WWDC 2012 [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242). Using Allocations tool in Instruments you can identify what is being allocated and not being released and those videos will illustrate how to do that (as well as outline categories of memory issues).